# Reading data from file to linked list is very slow

Tags: c++, list, large-files

I have a big problem, I have created linked list and data structure on  my own, but data reading function works very slow. If I try to read 10k structures function takes about 530 ms:

```
List size: 10000
Time: 530
Delete success
Press any key to continue . . .
```

But when I try to read 10 times bigger amount of data(it is 100k) it takes about 44500ms:

```
List size: 100000
Time: 44512
Delete success
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Here is my code:

IQ_struct.h

```
#ifndef IQ_sturct_H
#define IQ_struct_H

class IQ_struct {
public:
    IQ_struct();
    void setIQ(float, float);
    float getIQ();
    float getIQx();
    float getIQy();
    ~IQ_struct();
private:
    float newX;
    float newY;
};

#endif
```

IQ_struct.cpp

```
#include "IQ_struct.h"

IQ_struct::IQ_struct(){
    newX = 0;
    newY = 0;
}

IQ_struct::~IQ_struct(){}

void IQ_struct::setIQ(float x, float y){
    newX = x;
    newY = y;
}

float IQ_struct::getIQx(){
    return newX;
}

float IQ_struct::getIQy(){
    return newY;
}
```

IQ_data.h

```
#include <string>
#include "IQ_struct.h";

#ifndef IQ_data_H
#define IQ_data_H

class IQ_data{

public:
    IQ_data();
    void AddData(float, float);
    void Begin();
    void Next();
    bool End();
    IQ_struct GetData();
    void ReadFromFile(std::string,int);
    int GetSize();
    ~IQ_data();


private:
    typedef struct TNode{
        IQ_struct data;
        TNode *next;
    }* nodePtr;

    nodePtr head;
    nodePtr curr;
    nodePtr temp;
    int size;
};

#endif
```

IQ_data.cpp

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include "IQ_data.h"

using namespace std;

IQ_data::IQ_data(){
    head = NULL;
    curr = NULL;
    temp = NULL;
    size = 0;
}

void IQ_data::AddData(float x, float y){
    nodePtr n = new TNode;
    n->next = NULL;
    n->data.setIQ(x,y);

    if(head != NULL){
        curr = head;
        while(curr->next != NULL){
            curr = curr->next;
        }
        curr->next = n;
    }else{
        head = n;
    }
}


void IQ_data::Begin(){
    curr = head;
}

void IQ_data::Next(){
    curr = curr->next;
}

bool IQ_data::End(){
    return curr == NULL;
}
IQ_struct IQ_data::GetData(){
    return curr->data;
}

void IQ_data::ReadFromFile(string fileName,int a){
    float x,y;
    fstream myfile(fileName, ios_base::in);
    for(int k = 0; k < a; k++){
        myfile >> x;
        myfile >> y;
        AddData(x,y);
        size = size + 1;
    }
    myfile.close();
}

int IQ_data::GetSize(){
    return size;
}

IQ_data::~IQ_data(){
    while (head != NULL){
        curr = head;
        head = head->next;
        delete curr;
    }
    delete temp;
    delete head;
    curr = NULL;
    delete curr;
    cout << "Delete success \n";
}
```

Main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <omp.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include "IQ_data.h"

using namespace std;


int main(){
    IQ_data listas;
    clock_t init, fin;
    init = clock();
    listas.ReadFromFile("0.0013.txt",100000);
    fin = clock() - init;
    cout <<"List size: "<< listas.GetSize() << endl;
    cout <<"Time: "<<fin<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

What I'm doing wrong? The main problem is that my file contains over 5000K structures.
Thanks for help in advance :)

Comment: Before analyzing manually the code. Run performance analysis tools like valgrind or perf. However, what is your platform?

Comment: "I have a big problem, I have created linked list ... on my own" - because STL container classes weren't good enough?

Comment: You can save tail of your list for adding, also first try to use `std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false)`. Also try to read data into some big buffer and then parse it. Reading from disk is very slow operation.

Answer (score 3):

You're adding to the end of the list, so you need to traverse the entire list each time, which takes longer as the list gets longer.

Either add to the head of the list, or keep a pointer to the last element so you can insert there quickly.

Comment: Yup, that's S.O.P. Or, have a doubly linked, or circularly linked list. Or just use the STL container classes, like ordinary mortals.